# How to get filtered devices from one signal REST api

Tags: php, filtering, onesignal

i'm using onesignal to push notifications to users of an android app, all subscribed users have their email as an external_user_id.

I need display all subscribed devices to the user (in case he would want to unsubscribe remotely to the app). At the moment this can be done with rest api (https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/view-devices) however i would need to filter the resulting object myself for the desired devices and there is a limit to how much data can return from the endpoint.

I have not found a filter for this endpoint in the documentation so i ask if there is another way to get the desired data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I have used this API to get onesignal devices `"https://onesignal.com/api/v1/players?app_id=" . $app_id` and with the following code you can limit returned data:

```
$limit = 50;
$offset = 0;
            
$query = [
   'limit' => max(1, min(50, filter_var($limit, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))),
   'offset' => max(0, filter_var($offset, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)),
   'app_id' => $app_id,
];
    
$response = file_get_contents("https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications?view_notification_type=api&".http_build_query($query), false, $context);
```

Comment: Thank you but that i already know, it can be found in the api documentation, wha i need is this but filtering only for a specific external id, or even a tag would do.